# PHP Curl certinfo empty

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I have a script in PHP that does a curl request to a webservice. The request is made from my server that has an SSL installed and the webservice I send request too has also an SSL.

```
 $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://webservice.com?wsdl");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60000);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);//My post data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "../cacerts.pem");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH, "../cacerts.pem");
        $headers = [];
        array_push($headers, 'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
        array_push($headers, 'SoapAction: *');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        $content = trim(curl_exec($ch));
        var_dump($content);
        var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
        var_dump(curl_errno($ch));
        var_dump(curl_error($ch));
        curl_close($ch);
```

The debug info I get is as bellow:

```
array (size=26)
  'url' => string 'https://webservice.com?wsdl' (length=42)
  'content_type' => string 'text/xml;charset=utf-8' (length=22)
  'http_code' => int 200
  'header_size' => int 165
  'request_size' => int 901
  'filetime' => int -1
  'ssl_verify_result' => int 0
  'redirect_count' => int 0
  'total_time' => float 1.469
  'namelookup_time' => float 0.25
  'connect_time' => float 0.688
  'pretransfer_time' => float 1.188
  'size_upload' => float 632
  'size_download' => float 536
  'speed_download' => float 364
  'speed_upload' => float 430
  'download_content_length' => float 536
  'upload_content_length' => float 632
  'starttransfer_time' => float 1.469
  'redirect_time' => float 0
  'redirect_url' => string '' (length=0)
  'primary_ip' => string 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (length=15)
  'certinfo' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'primary_port' => int 443
  'local_ip' => string 'xx.xx.xx.x' (length=10)
  'local_port' => int 61993
```

Is it normal that the "certinfo" is an empty array? If not why is it empty.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may need to set the following option to have "certinfo" populated

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, 1);
```

Comment: did nothing for me... :-(

Comment: Apparently there was a bug that made it empty: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54816874/5078765

Comment: "CURLOPT_CERTINFO  true to output SSL certification information to STDERR on secure transfers. " https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php
It's purpose is not what is described in this answer. Perhaps the answer could provide a source.