# curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CERTINFO) is empty

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I have PHP 7.2 from [IUS](https://ius.io/GettingStarted/) repository, but the same behavior is on default PHP (CentOS 7.x).

Code:

```
$domain = "google.com";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://' . $domain);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

curl_exec($ch);
$certInfo = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CERTINFO);

curl_close($ch);
```

Variable **$certInfo** is empty. I have tested curl with https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check and it is supporting TLS 1.2.

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips
cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.29.0
Age => 3
Features
AsynchDNS => Yes
CharConv => No
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => Yes
IDN => Yes
IPv6 => Yes
krb4 => No
Largefile => Yes
libz => Yes
NTLM => Yes
NTLMWB => Yes
SPNEGO => No
SSL => Yes
SSPI => No
TLS-SRP => No
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host => x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
SSL Version => NSS/3.36
ZLib Version => 1.2.7
libSSH Version => libssh2/1.4.3
```

What is wrong? curl? openssl? nss?

Comment: have you tried in other domains than goggle?

Answer (score 2):

Try it with this: (updated domain)

```
$domain = "www.google.com";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://' . $domain);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

curl_exec($ch);
$certInfo = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CERTINFO);

curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem, you need to update curl and libcurl to newer version, for example 7.42.0.

Fixed in 7.42.0 - April 22 2015

```
Changes:

    openssl: show the cipher selection to use in verbose text
    gtls: implement CURLOPT_CERTINFO
    add CURLOPT_SSL_FALSESTART option (darwinssl and NSS)
    curl: add --false-start option
    add CURLOPT_PATH_AS_IS
    curl: add --path-as-is option
    curl: create output file on successful download of an empty file
```

And for CentOS 7.x:

```
7.34 bugfix ->  NSS: support for CERTINFO feature
```